# Show hidden div on menu hover in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, show, hidden

I have a menu that on hover will show a hidden div with submenu options. It works fine in Chrome & Firefox but I recently noticed after putting the site live that it didn't work in IE of some reason. I've been checking the code and can't really find the problem so far. I hope someone else can see what I miss here!

Site: http://www.reseportalen.nu and its when you hover over the blue menu in header.

This is the css for hovering that works in all except IE so far.

```
#main-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

and this is the hidden UL

```
#main-nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
display: none;
float: left;
width: 203px;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #207DDA;

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
left bottom,
color-stop(0, #207DDA),
color-stop(1, #1461B4)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #207DDA 0%, #1461B4 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #207DDA 0%, #1461B4 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #207DDA 0%, #1461B4 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #207DDA 0%, #1461B4 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #207DDA 0%, #1461B4 100%);
}
```

I think you see pretty clearly on the site what I mean by this. Anyways this browser Internet Explorer always give me a headache.

Have a nice evening all!

Comment: You're running your app in Quirks mode, please add a valid DTD to your document.

Comment: Problem solved. Added <!DOCTYPE HTML> on the top of the document and <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" > in <head> element. 

Had totaly missed that. Hope it helps someone in the future!